# discord.js reaction for play function

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I am pretty sure it means message is not defined but why I think I defined it does anyone know what is the problem? I tried everything I can. it sends this error (There was an error connecting to the voice channel: TypeError: Cannot read property 'react' of undefined)

```js
function play(guild, song, client, message) {
    const serverQueue = client.queue.get(guild.id)
    const loop = client.loop.get(guild.id)

    console.log(loop)

    if (!song) {
        serverQueue.voiceChannel.leave()
        client.queue.delete(guild.id)
        return
    }

    const dispatcher = serverQueue.connection.play(ytdl(song.url))
        .on('finish', () => {
            if (loop === undefined) {
                serverQueue.songs.shift()
            }
            play(guild, serverQueue.songs[0], client, message)
        })
        .on('error', error => {
            console.log(error)
        })
    dispatcher.setVolumeLogarithmic(serverQueue.volume / 5)
    if (loop === undefined) {
        const reaction = (reaction) => reaction.emoji.name === '⏭️';
        serverQueue.textChannel.send(`Playing: **${song.title}**`)
        message.react('⏭️') 
        .then(console.log) 
        .catch(console.error);
    message.awaitReactions((reaction) => (reaction.emoji.name == '⏭️'),
            { max: 1 }).then(collected => {
            if (collected.first().emoji.name == '⏭️') {
              if(!message.member.voice.channel) return message.channel.send("You need to be in a voice channel to skip the music")
                 if(!serverQueue) return message.channel.send("There is nothing to playing")
                  serverQueue.connection.dispatcher.end()
                   client.loop.delete(message.guild.id)
                         }
     return undefined
    
        
    })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right. Inside `play(<args>){...}` function you try to call `.react()` on `undefined`. Could you give more context to this problem? Like the calling context to see why `play(<args>){}` receives no value for its 4th parameter, message.

Comment: i can send you the whole code if you want https://hatebin.com/vzdnkyrqbk

Comment: thanks, I don't see the context where `play(<args>)` the function defined on line `121` is called. What is calling it?

Comment: it is the above so the function play is defined from the above at least that what I did

Comment: there is no 4th `parameter` passed to the function on line `137` in the example provided by you on `hatebin`.